# Regex expression for Checkstyle to match on missing @Ignore comments

Tags: regex, checkstyle

I'm trying to create a custom Checkstyle rule which will flag as an error when developers use `@Ignore` without a comment. Therefore I'm looking for a regular expression which matches the following scenario:

```
@Ignore
@Test
public void someTest() {
   ...
}
```

and this one:

```
@Ignore @Test    //or @Test @Ignore
public void someTest() {
   ...
}
```

but would not match this scenario:

```
@Ignore("some comment detailing why this test was ignored")
@Test
public void someTest() {
   ...
}
```

or this one:

```
@Test
public void someTest() {
   ...
}
```

So basically its a regular expression matching `@Ignore` but only when its present and only when its present without qualifying comments, e.g. `@Ignore("commnent here")`

Comment: Which regex engine are you using? Solutions might differ a bit depending on this (as explained in the [Regex tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info))

Comment: @Tim, I would assume it is Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Ignore(?![ \t]*\()
```

matches `@Ignore` only if it's not followed by an opening parenthesis.

**Explanation:**

```
@Ignore   # Match "@Ignore"
(?!       # Assert that we can't match...
 [ \t]*   # optional spaces/tabs
 \(       # followed by a ( at the current position
)         # End of lookahead
```

In Java:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("@Ignore(?![ \\t]*\\()");
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Looks like this will work for my original example above.  However, as Kent pointed out, there is another scenario I forgot about (now added to my question)

Comment: @Chris: OK, I've rewritten my answer. Is that working for you? Specifically, is it possible for spaces/tabs or other whitespace to occur between `@Ignore` and the comment?

Comment: yes its possible for spaces to be between the `@Ignore` and the comment.  E.g. `@Ignore ("some comment")` is valid (e.g. shouldn't match)

Answer (score 1):

you could try this out:

```
@Ignore\s*$
```

actually for junit test, annotation:

```
@Test @Ignore
public void testXXXX(){}
```

also valid. so this needs to be matched too.

**updated**

this should be ok:

```
@Ignore\s*(?!\()
```

Comment: Thanks Kent.  I like the simplicity of yours, except that it doesn't work when you have `@Ignore @Test'.

Comment: I guess you are doing some code review. with an IDE maybe? IDE has usually code formatter/ checkStyle features. you can define adding new line after annotation. (one annotation per line) it is not only for this question, but also make the code more readable.

Comment: Thanks Kent, totally agree and we're starting to use automated code formatting, but we have lots of legacy code which does not have a consistent format.  Sorry, wish I could accept your answer too!